# Method Visible not supported by automation object (PivotItem)

Tags: excel, delphi

```
Procedure TExcel.VisibleCampoPivot (Campo : OleVariant; Index : ShortString; Value : boolean );
var FPivotItem : OleVariant;
begin
  try
    FPivotItem := Campo.PivotItems;
    FPivotItem.Visible := Value;
  except
  end;
end;
```

```
FPivotField := MyExcel.AddCampoPivot(FPivotTable, LineaHeader[_CodSeccion].Valor, xlPageField);
MyExcel.LabelCampoPivot(FPivotField, LineaHeader[_CodSeccion].Valor);
MyExcel.VisibleCampoPivot(FPivotField, BlankCell, False); <--- Not Supported
```

When I try to set the Visible property on PivotItem it generates the error.

Comment: `PivotItems` is a collection. It has no `Visible` property.

Comment: You need to set the `Visible` property on a *specific item* inside the `PivotItems` collection, not on the collection itself.

Comment: Hint: The `Index` that is passed into the procedure is there for a reason. Also, `PivotItems` is plural, meaning more than one, which means it's a collection. `PivotItem` (without the `s`), is one `PivotItem`.

Comment: ok, yes... i change my code to 
´´ 
    FPivotItem := Campo.PivotItems (Index);
    FPivotItem.Visible := Value;
´´
and i get other error. That says "Error in the PivotItem method of the PivotField class"